# How to make jQuery rendered content editable in Sitecore experience editor

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

We have a Sitecore project and the code/files are from an **ASP.NET** web application.

The HTML for the products section is as follows

```
<div class="products-section">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="product">
     <h3>Product Name</h3>
     <img src="/images/img1.jpg" />
     <span>Description</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it works for an end user.
EU will click on a Product tab (eg: Product 1), which will change the content inside `<div class="product">`, **without postback**.

For the author, this section must be editable from the Experience editor. Usually, I would use `asp:Repeater` with `sc:Text,sc:Image` to render it.

But, here the data has to be retrieved using ajax calls, which means no Repeater or Sitecore controls.

In such case, how can I make the content editable from Experience editor.

The only ideas I came up with:

1. Get data of all the products in `Page_Load`, bind it using `Repeater` and then use `jQuery` to Show/Hide the respective divs. (doesn't seem a nice way though)
2. Tell the content author, that this section can only be edited from Content editor and not from the experience editor :)

What are my options here.

Comment: Why close this? Isn't this a common scenario for sitecore devs. If there is something else that needs to be mentioned, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to render your page differently when in the experience editor. Check the mode in your code and use a repeater when editing, otherwise use the jquery output. 
You can use Views to easily display/hide the output you want.

```
<asp:MultiView runat="server" ID="ProductsView">
  <asp:View runat="server" ID="StandardView">
    <div ...>
     ...
    </div>
  </asp:View>
  <asp:View runat="server" ID="EditorView">
    <asp:Repeater..>
       ...
    </asp:Repeater>
  </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

In your code behind:

```
ProductsView.SetActiveView((Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing) ? EditorView : StandardView)
```

Based on the active view, you can decide to attach data to the repeater or not (don't do that when the StandardView is active, for performance)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Gatogordo. Please provide some more insight, pointers to help me get started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why would an end user interact with Experience Editor as Experience editor is used by Content Authors for authoring the site and updating the content on the Page itself.

But if this is a requirement for a Content Author you can use the sitecore services client api for updating the content using ajax call. 
Use [this document](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf) to see how ssc works.

Let me know if you have a different ask.

Comment: My post doesn't say EU will edit ! It was only to explain how it works for the EU. The content of course should be updated by ajax, but at the same time the author, should be able to edit via Experience editor. Appreciate. if you can point to an example instead. If you did not get the question, please let me know.

Comment: I think you should create another view for the Experience editor mode and render it based on the display mode. And for doing that you can extend the MVC display mode and extend the controllerrendering and viewrendering to be able to handle the PageEditor views.

Comment: Can you please provide any link for reference. Also, this is an ASP.NET and not MVC. Will it work

Comment: @Qwerty : Is it WebForms? I think in Webforms also you can use the server tags <%={your condition}%> and then use below condition to render the code
Use `if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing) or 
 if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor

let me know if that helps.

Comment: Also you can try this link which shows how to use PageEditor mode but this talks about Razor view so you would need to use it as i mentioned above using server tags in WebForms - [Link](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/martina-welander-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/07/improving-the-page-editor-experience-part-3-detecting-page-mode.aspx)
let me know if that helps.